# CPUID output depends on order of operations

Tags: assembly, bios, cpuid

I am writing a toy OS, which is supposed to be a command line. I have tried adding CPUID to my functionality, and I get weird results when I call CPUID in consecutive order, i.e. `80000002h`, `80000003h`, `80000004h`. If I call it in any other order, it works fine.

Consecutive order

[image: Consecutive order]

Another order:

[image: Another order]

This is the offending part of the code.

```
prcpuinf:
    push dx

    mov eax, 80000002h
    cpuid
    mov [es:cpuinfo+0], eax
    mov [es:cpuinfo+4], ebx
    mov [es:cpuinfo+8], ecx
    mov [es:cpuinfo+12], edx  

    mov eax, 80000003h
    cpuid
    mov [es:cpuinfo+16], eax
    mov [es:cpuinfo+20], ebx
    mov [es:cpuinfo+24], ecx
    mov [es:cpuinfo+28], edx
    mov eax, 80000004h
    cpuid
;    jmp prnt
    mov [es:cpuinfo+32], eax
    mov [es:cpuinfo+36], ebx
    mov [es:cpuinfo+40], ecx
    mov [es:cpuinfo+44], edx
    nop
prnt:

    mov ah, 13h    
    mov ecx, 48;cpulen
    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, 0x07
    mov dh, 3
    mov dl, 3
    mov bp, cpuinfo
    int 10h

    pop dx
    mov ecx, 1
    ret
```

The code behaves this way even if I don't copy the last part of the CPU Brand String, i.e. when uncommenting `jmp prnt.

Because this part works normally in a file by itself, I have posted my entire code [here](http://pastebin.com/RM1uR6X2).

Please note, I am not looking for a solution, but rather for an explanation to what is happening.

Comment: In the first order, every odd byte is the character, and every even byte are its [attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_color_attributes). Why does this happen? Because `AL` specifies the subservice, as noted in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556973/how-does-int-10-13h-work-with-attributes). Set `AL` to `0` or `1` to get what you want.

Comment: @Rhymid Answers go in the box below!

Comment: @JensBjörnhager I know, I just want to have it nicely written before I provide it as an answer ;)

Comment: @Rhymoid writing code at 3 in the morning isn't good for the interrupts. Thanks. If you care turning  your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I've had a good night's sleep, so I just turned it into an answer. Enjoy tinkering with your toy OS! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** always specify `AX` entirely.

---

Let's look at this piece of code:

```
mov ah, 13h
mov ecx, 48;cpulen
mov bh, 0
mov bl, 0x07
mov dh, 3
mov dl, 3
mov bp, cpuinfo
int 10h
```

You defined `AH`, `BX`, `CX`, `DX`, and `BP`. You didn't define `AL`, which is also part of the interface for `INT 10h`. In case of `AH=13h`, `AL` specifies the subservice, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556973/how-does-int-10-13h-work-with-attributes):

- `AL=0h`: `BP` is a character string and `BL` specifies the attribute, do not update the cursor
- `AL=1h`: `BP` is a character string and `BL` specifies the attribute, update the cursor
- `AL=2h`: `BP` is a string of character-attribute pairs, do not update the cursor
- `AL=3h`: `BP` is a string of character-attribute pairs, update the cursor

I think that actual implementations just look at the least significant bits of `AL`, and decide what to do. Specifically, in your case, whenever bit 1 of `AL` is set, you see the garbled text, but when it's reset, you see the normal text.

So whether you see garbled or normal text depends on what the last call to `CPUID` wrote to bit 1 of `AL`. This is exactly why it depends on the order of calls.